# OSX - Compiling a Java JNI application to run with only JRE installed

Tags: java, macos

I'm writing a native application that uses JNI to create a Java virtual machine and run some code on it.  This application is meant to be distributed for others to use, so it needs to work on other computers, not just mine.  This all works fine on the PC, but on the Mac, there are all sorts of problems.

If I use the Java framework built-in to Xcode, then I can use JNI provided all my code is compiled to Java Version 6 -- because Xcode's Java framework apparently ended support at Java 6.

I can use a later version of Java if I install the JDK and cleverly link to the libjvm.dlib, libjli.dylib, and libjava.dylib files.  Everything ran great in this scenario, which was pretty cool.  So I tried running this on another Mac that didn't have the JDK installed, just the JRE, and I discovered that it didn't work!  Even though jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib exists in the JDK, it turns out it does not exist in the JRE.

My question is: is there any way to create a Java 8 or Java 9 VM that will run on Mac OSX with just the JRE installed, and not the JDK?

Comment: Try loading `jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib` via `dlopen` and calling the functions that way. I had same problem as you and found no solution. So far I dynamically link and it works fine on my own comp. I use `getenv("JAVA_HOME")` to find the JRE.

Comment: "it didn't work!" -- we're going to need more to go on.  How exactly did it fail?  My first guess is that you didn't set the dylib `@executable_path`s correctly, but that's just a hunch.

Comment: Hi Brandon, that's a pretty good solution, but my main problem is that jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib doesn't seem to exist if you install just the Java Runtime Envrionment and not the Java Development Kit.  Is there any way to get this to work with just the JRE?

Comment: Ssswift, as I explained, it didn't work because libjvm.dylib does not appear to be included when you install just the JRE.  It appears to require the entire JDK to be installed.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... I'm not completely sure I understand what your asking, but I'm gonna answer based on what the problem seems to be to me. I have to ask, did you make sure you packaged your Java program correctly into a .jar file? If that isn't the issue, I will say that I know normally you can bundle libraries and other packages in Java. I don't honestly know if that would be an option for you, as I don't know of those files you mentioned, but that could be a possible solution for you.

Sorry I can't provide more info than that. Hopefully someone else will be more familiar with this specific part of Java.